# Using single ref for multiple input fields in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I am trying to use the same ref for multiple input fields in for my form. But on logging it, the ref refers only to the first input field. Is there anyway I can use the same ref and use for different inputs?

```
import React, {FC, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import { IFormProps } from '../../utils/Interfaces';
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'

const Form:FC<IFormProps> = ({formData, handleFormData, errors, handleValidate}) => {
  const inputField = React.useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  
  return (
    <form className='user-form'>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          ref = {inputField}
          value={formData.firstName} 
          name="firstName" id="firstName" 
          onChange={(e) => handleFormData(e)} placeholder="Enter your first name"
          onFocus={() => console.log('focus')} 
          onBlur={() => handleValidate(inputField)}
          />
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            value={formData.lastName} 
            name="lastName" id="lastName" 
            onChange={(e) => handleFormData(e)} 
            placeholder="Enter the last name"
            onBlur={() => handleValidate(inputField)}
            ref = {inputField}
        />
    </form>

  )
}

export default Form;
```

I am passing this information to the parent to handle validation. I am not sure how I can pass the same ref(inputField) as different input elements with its attributes.

I have tried doing this [Use a single ref object across multiple input elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72262303/use-a-single-ref-object-across-multiple-input-elements), but there is an error saying the following. I am aware its cause of typescript. But not sure how to handle it.

```
ref = {(el) => (inputField.current["firstName"] = el)}
```

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"firstName"' can't be used to index type 'HTMLInputElement'.
  Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typescript, most hooks are generic. You declare their type using `<>`.
If you want to assign to properties `firstName` and `lastName` then declare them in your type. You will also need to initialize the object.

```
  const inputField = React.useRef<{
    firstName: HTMLInputElement;
    lastName: HTMLInputElement;
  }>({ firstName: null, lastName: null });

  return (
    <form className="user-form">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input
        ref={(ref) => (inputField.current.firstName = ref)}
        ...
      />
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input
        ref={(ref) => (inputField.current.lastName = ref)}
        ...
      />
    </form>
  );
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zkc3nj?file=App.tsx

Comment: Thank you very much. It works! The example is of great help!